# Is it possible to assign a vector<int> value to std::unordered<int,std::vector<int>> in one line?

Tags: c++, c++11

You can create a vector by doing:

```
std::vector<int> v = ({1,2,3});
```

Suppose you have:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::vector<int>> m;
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```
m[1] = ({1,2,3});
```

i.e. Is there a way to assign the values in the parenthesis without having to go through the two line step of creating a vector first and then assigning ?

```
std::vector<int> v = ({1,2,3});
m[1] = v;
```

Is there anyway to condense the above two lines into a one line step ? Or is the only alternative, to create a function which takes the values that go into the vector and return a vector:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T> func2( std::initializer_list<T> list )
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    for( auto elem : list )
    {
        v.push_back(elem) ;
    }
    return v;
}
```

and then do:

```
m[1] = func2({1,2,3});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m[1] = {1, 2, 3};
```

Drop the parentheses.

Comment: @John: It doesn't.